# Is there a way to make a constructor that draws a rectangle

Tags: java, graphics

My partner and I are trying to remake Tetris for our final project of the year in my Computer Science class we currently have a for loop that draws individual rectangles in an overwritten paint method.

```
private final int spacer = 30;
public int getSpacer()
{
    return spacer;
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {    
    setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    for(int i = getHeight()/2 - (spacer * 10); i < getHeight()/2 + (spacer * 10); i += spacer) {
        for(int x = getWidth()/2 - (spacer * 5); x < getWidth()/2 + (spacer * 5); x += (spacer)) {
            g.drawRect(x, i, (spacer), (spacer));
        }
    }
    setForeground(Color.black);
}
```

The method basically takes the width and height of the window and makes a 10 x 20 grid of boxes that are 30 units, pixels I think, wide.

We'd like to make a Grid.java class that takes in color, the spacer int, and an x and y int. The constructor for Grid.java should draw the exact same thing as the code above using the for loop, but when we tried it gave us a white screen that would not resize with the window.

```
private final int spacer = 30;
private static Grid[][] arr = new Grid[10][20];

public int getSpacer()
{
    return spacer;
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {    
    setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    int countY = 0;
    int countX = 0;
    for(int y = getHeight()/2 - (spacer * 10); y < getHeight()/2 + (spacer * 10); y += spacer) {
        for(int x = getWidth()/2 - (spacer * 5); x < getWidth()/2 + (spacer * 5); x += spacer) {
            arr[countX][countY] = new Grid(x, y, spacer, g);
            countX++;
        }
        countY++;
    }
    setForeground(Color.black);
}

*Grid.java Class*

package Tetris_Shapes;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Grid {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int side;
    private Graphics g;

    public Grid(int x, int y, int side, Graphics g) {
        // g.drawRect(x, y, spacer, spacer);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.side = side;
        this.g = g;
        paint(this.g);
    }

    private void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(x, y, side, side);
    }
}
```

When we try and run this we get the white box that doesn't resize. My question is does anyone know of a way to get a constructor to draw shapes. Thank you in advance, this is pretty niche so I'm also going to apologize in advance.

Comment: First you should be overriding `paintComponent()`, not `paint()`.  This could be the source of some of your trouble. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html

Comment: Second you really *do not* want to make a constructor that does painting.  Yeeikes.    Make an object (a "screen" or a "game") that paints the tetris shapes.  Make the shapes just regular objects, they don't need a paint method.  You have too many "paint" methods above and I think you're getting confused which needs to be called.  Simplify.

Comment: @markspace when you say make shapes that are regular object, how do you paint those out. For example, How would I define the L shape, then get it to paint?

Comment: Hmm, I probably wouldn't give it a literal `paint()` method, but I might give it `draw()` (arbitrary name) method that takes a `Graphics` and updates its position.  That may be a subtle distinction but it does make it easier to test and decompose/encapsulate (and delegate behavior).  Don't forget that tetris shapes can also be rotated, you'll have to draw that as well.

Comment: @markspace, I think I get what you're saying, I'll try some stuff out tonight and see what happens, thank you so much!